Investigating the stability of a wooden block

Consider the above experimental design. At the end of the strip, at point $p$, a mass $m$ is attached, the stability of the wooden block above is determined by the angle $θ$ at which the block topples over. It seems that as the angle $θ$, approaches $0$ the block becomes easier to topple over. However, I am struggling to come up with a suitable reason for why.
At all values of the angle $θ$, the distance of the mass $m$ from the centre of the mass remains constant. Hence, the only thing that changes is the area of the strip over the top of the block. So then, is a suitable explanation, that the force downwards by the mass $m$ is distributed over a larger area, making the turning effect of the force less?
Another explanation I have come up with, is that the edge of the block that the strip is over, acts as the pivot for the mass $m$. As the strip angle increases, the distance between $p$ and the pivot actually decreases, therefore making the turning effect of the force less. Is this suitable?
I am looking for a sound physics explanation for the phenomena above. My attempts at explanations do not seem correct.

Stability and toppling

"edge of the block that the strip is over" Yes, that is the reason.

This seems to be a conceptual question with a conceptual answer.  Voting to re-open.


Another explanation I have come up with, is that the edge of the block that the strip is over, acts as the pivot for the mass $m$

This is the correct explanation. If the block (or the bench that it sits on) is tilted, it will topple once a vertical line through the centre of gravity of the block/mass system moves outside of the base of the block. Decreasing the angle $\theta$ moves the mass at $P$ further away from the block, thus moving the centre of gravity of the block/mass system towards the right hand edge of the block, making the block easier to topple. If $m$ is sufficiently large compared to the mass of the block then there may even be an angle $\theta > 0$ at which the centre of gravity moves outside of the block and the block topples without being tilted.
